# Setting Variable with VLookup & Named Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, named-ranges

I can not get the `VLookup` function to work when using a named range. I am sure it has something to do with how I am referencing `"COA_Range"` but cant find a solution that works

I have tried [], ([]), (""), [""],([""])......

(*Below is an updated and expanded section of the code*)

```
If Transaction_Type = 1 Then
    Debug.Print "Transaction Type :"; Transaction_Type
    Range("n10").Value = "Income"

    Debug.Print "COA # = "; TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value
    COA_Number = TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value
    Debug.Print COA_Number

    Range("n12").Value = TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value

    'thought from STACK OVERFLOW
    Debug.Print Range("COA_Range").Address()

    COA_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(COA_Number, Range("COA_Range"), 2, False)
    Debug.Print COA_1
    Range("n13").Value = COA_1
```

Comment: What's `TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number`? You can also refer named range by `Thisworkbook.Names("COA_Range").RefersToRange`.

Comment: it is a value taken from a userform. TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value works throughout the rest of my macro. your "thisworkbook.names..." was unsuccessful

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print Range("COA_Range").Address()` to make sure the range is found.

Comment: Yes the range is being found Range().Address() --> immediate --> $B$8:$F$41

Comment: All of your test are ambiguous as to whether `TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value` is a true number or text-that-looks-like-a-number. I suspect it is the latter and the values in column B of `Range("COA_Range")` are true numbers. VLOOKUP cannot find  text-that-looks-like-a-number within a column of true numebers. Convert with `CLng(TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value2)` to get a true number. Of course, if `COA_Number ` had been declared as a long instead of not-at-all or a variant then this would have been immediately obvious.

Comment: Thanks @jeeped your answer worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @jainashish, @Shai Rado for the thoughtful responses. I was able to pick up a few pointers from each.

It was @Jeeped however who actually solved my problem. The "number" was being read as text and the CLng() expression worked for me. I have added my updated code below.

```
    If Transaction_Type = 1 Then
    Debug.Print "Transaction Type :"; Transaction_Type
        Range("n10").Value = "Income"

        'thought from STACKOVERFLOW
            'need to make sure that the number taken fromt the userform is ACTUALLY a number and not text that looks like a number
                'use CLng to convert

    Debug.Print "COA # = "; CLng(TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value)
        COA_Number = CLng(TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value)
            Debug.Print "COA # = "; COA_Number
        Range("n12").Value = COA_Number

            'thought from STACK OVERFLOW
                Debug.Print Range("COA_Range").Address()
                    'Yes the range is being found...
                        Dim COA_Range As Range
                        Set COA_Range = Range("COA_Range")
                            Debug.Print COA_Range.Address()

        COA_1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(COA_Number, Range("COA_Range"), 2, False)
                Debug.Print COA_1
                    Range("n13").Value = COA_1

        COA_2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(COA_Number, Range("COA_Range"), 3, False)
                Debug.Print COA_2
                    Range("n14").Value = COA_2

        COA_3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(COA_Number, Range("COA_Range"), 4, False)
                Debug.Print COA_3
                    Range("n15").Value = COA_3

        COA_4 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(COA_Number, Range("COA_Range"), 5, False)
                Debug.Print COA_4
                    Range("n16").Value = COA_4enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @Jeeped comment, make sure that the value in your User_Form named "**TransactionInfo**" in the TextBox "**Income_COA_Number**" has a Numeric value, and so all the values in your `Range("COA_Range")` cells.

I've added 2 optional solutions (pick the one you prefer):

- Using `Application.Match`.
- Using `Find`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub VLookUpNamedRange()

Dim ws                  As Worksheet
Dim Transaction_Type    As Long
Dim MyCOARng            As Range
Dim COA_1               As Variant
Dim COA_Number          As Long
Dim FndRng              As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet7") '<-- modify "Sheet7" to your sheet's name    
Set MyCOARng = ws.Range("COA_Range") '<-- set Range to "COA_Range" Named Range

COA_Number = TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value
 
' === Option 1: Use Application.Match ===
If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(COA_Number, MyCOARng, 2, False)) Then ' <-- VLookup Successful
    COA_1 = Application.VLookup(COA_Number, MyCOARng, 2, False)
Else ' <-- VLookup failed
    COA_1 = COA_Number & " Not found in 'COA_Range' "
End If
    
' === Option 2: Use Find ===
Set FndRng = MyCOARng.Find(What:=COA_Number, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then '<-- successful find
    COA_1 = FndRng.Offset(, 2).Value
Else '<-- not found in your range
    COA_1 = COA_Number & " Not found in 'COA_Range' "
End If
 
Debug.Print COA_1 ' <-- for DEBUG Only

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have posted my exact solution below

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ***Application.Vlookup*** instead of using **Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup**. Then set a Variant equal to this and if no match is found then it would return Error 2042 which can be tested using IsError

See the Example Code below:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet            'Change the sheet reference appropriately
Dim rngLookUpTable As Range: Set rngLookUpTable = ws.Range("COA_Range")    
Dim vReturn As Variant

If Transaction_Type = 1 Then
    Range("N10").Value = "Income"
    COA_Number = TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value
    Range("N12").Value = TransactionInfo.Income_COA_Number.Value
    vReturn = Application.VLookup(COA_Number,rngLookUpTable, 2, False)
    Range("N13").Value = IIF(IsError(vReturn),"Not Found",vReturn)
End If
```

WorksheetFunction version of VLookup and Match need error handling that re-routes your code to an error handler, returns to the next statement to evaluate, etc. With the Application functions, you can avoid that mess.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have posted my exact solution below